# Installing GDAL via buildout on MacOSX

Tags: django, macos, buildout, geodjango, gdal

I'm trying to install GDAL via buildout on MacOSX. I have following config:

```
[gdal]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/gdal-1.7.2.tar.gz
extra_options =
    --with-geos=${geos:location}/bin/geos-config
    --with-static-proj4=${proj:location}
    --with-jpeg={libjpeg:location}
    --with-spatialite=${spatialite-lib:location}
    --with-sqlite=${spatialite-lib:location}
```

I tried many other configurations but all I've got is the following error:
http://pastebin.com/s0WxfnUu

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the problem - description below.

Just for the record - proper configuration for building GDAL on MacOSX (for example purposes I've cut off additional stuff):

```
[libiconv]
# ...

[gdal]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.cmmi
url = http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/gdal-1.7.3.tar.gz
configure-options =
    --with-python
    --with-jpeg=internal
    --with-spatialite=${spatialite:location}
    CFLAGS=-I${libiconv:location}/include
    LIBS="${libiconv:location}/lib/libiconv.la ${libiconv:location}/lib/libcharset.la"
```

You need to specify libiconv (in my example I'm building it from source) - it will prevent charset errors.

Also my problem was in the version of jpeglib, so I've definied `--with-jpeg=internal` so the GDAL will use it's own libs. Depending on the error you can use `--with-png=internal`, `--with-tiff=internal` etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Buildout is great for a lot of things, but even I tend to hand over some responsibility to the OS.

The whole whopping geo stack is one of those things.  Gdal, geos, libproj4, mapnik, I don't know what.  Compiling everything from source is just too cumbersome, especially as you have a lot of dependencies.

In your case, it looks like there's a mismatch in some of the libraries that gdal compiles against.  Wrong length of arguments.

My tip is to install gdal and friends via your OS (so: windows installer, apt-get, rpm, whatever).

Comment: yeah - but I'd like to get easy replicable development enviroment - also for other developers... These are the reasons why I'm starting to hate Mac OSX :P

Comment: Why not get use a linux VM and MacFusion (or the like) to work on it over SSH? That's what I've done for my GeoDjango stack. Best of both worlds, then.

Comment: @stevejalim - I beg you, why not to buy another computer to run Linux on it - if I can't work on my computer then what do I need it for? :) I handled problem by myself and it seems that buildout is managing well with all that stuff.

Comment: Use homebrew: brew install gdal